# How to fix column-count issue with iframe in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe, cybersource

I have a layout that uses the column-count property to create a two column form. I cannot change the form template, so to implement two columns I have to use column-count.
However, I also need to embed an iframe that loads a Cybersource card payment form. The problem is, when using column-count the select elements for the expiry date (month and year) do not work. In other browsers as Safari it works.
Disabling column-count makes it also work in Chrome, but this is not an option, since I need the two column design.
Is there a way or workaround to also make it work with Chrome?